# Can you use a HMAC-SHA256 signature in authlib in python?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-1.0a, authlib

The [authlib documentation](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/1/customize.html) discusses how to process `HMAC-SHA256` signature methods server side, but there doesn't seem to be anything about how to sign requests with this kind of signature.

The following code fails with a `ValueError: Invalid signature method.`

```py
auth = OAuth1Auth(
    client_id="...",
    client_secret="...",
    token="...",
    token_secret="...",
    realm="...",
    signature_method= "HMAC-SHA256",
)
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=payload)
```

Is there a way to issue requests with `HMAC-SHA256`, or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post about using HMAC-SHA256 in OAuth 1 client:

https://blog.authlib.org/2023/oauth1-hmac-sha256

Copy the code here:

```
from authlib.oauth1 import ClientAuth


def hmac_sha256_signature(base_string, client_secret, token_secret):
    text = base_string
    key = escape(client_secret or '')
    key += '&'
    key += escape(token_secret or '')
    signature = hmac.new(to_bytes(key), to_bytes(text), hashlib.sha256)
    sig = binascii.b2a_base64(signature.digest())[:-1]
    return to_unicode(sig)

def sign_rsa_sha256(client, request):
    base_string = generate_signature_base_string(request)
    return hmac_sha256_signature(base_string, client.rsa_key)


ClientAuth.register_signature_method("HMAC-SHA256", sign_rsa_sha256)
```

Comment: [Please refrain from giving link-only answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/201534)